# How this term is generalised?

Tags: calculus

Q. 
Find the assymptotes of 
$r=\frac{2a}{1+2cos\theta}$

Sol.
Putting $u=\frac{1}{u}$, the equation of the curve becomes

$2au=1+2cos\theta$

When $\lim_{u \to 0}$, then $cos\theta_1=\frac{-1}{2}=cos\frac{2π}{3}$

$cos\theta_1=2nπ±\frac{2π}{3};$ $n=0,±1,±2,±3.....$

---

From where that  $cos\theta_1$ came ??

I mean

$cos\theta_1=\frac{-1}{2}=cos\frac{2π}{3}$

$cos\theta_1=2nπ±\frac{2π}{3};$ $n=0,±1,±2,±3.....$